# Access List<string[]> in wcf service

Tags: c#, string, list, wcf

I am a newbie to C# programming and completely stuck here.

My situation is I have a `List<String[]>` data object in one of the classes in my project. 
And I have to create a WCF service application in the same solution which should return that `List<string>` data object.

But the thing is how do I access that `List<String[]>` data in WCF service application.

I have to create a WCF service that returns this `List<String[]>`

Comment: You should be able to just create a method that returns a `List<string[]>`  What have you tried and what is not working?

Comment: No,I have that List<String[]> in another project.

Comment: Please post the code of your WCF service (how you think of it) and if something does not work for you - specify what does not work.